# asp.net core Windsor vs ConfigureServices

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core, castle-windsor

I went to asp.net core recently and I started using *ConfigureServices* instead of Windsor. I have two classes *MockDbContext* and *ProductionDbContext*, both of them inherit from *DbContext* class. How can I write the following code in ConfigureServices?

```
if (true) {
        container.Register(Component.For<DbContext>().UsingFactoryMethod(() => MockDbContext.GetMockDbContext()).LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient());
} else {
        container.Register(Component.For<DbContext>().ImplementedBy<ProductionDbContext>().LifeStyle.HybridPerWebRequestTransient());
}
```

I tried several options without any success. It seems like I have to make interface to distinguish both classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        if (true)
        {
            services.AddSingleton((_) => MockDbContext.GetMockDbContext());
        } else
        {
            services.AddScoped((_) => new ProductionDbContext());
        }
```